# Bootstrap 4: Convert button-group to dropdown for small screens

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I have a web app I am working on and I am using Bootstrap 4 for some of the components.
The forms and tables shows a few actions as buttons inside a button group. This is a sample piece of code:

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.1/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class=" btn-group">
  <a href='#' class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-danger"><i class="fa fa-key"></i> Change Password</a>
  <a href='#' class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-sm "><i class="fa fa-pencil-alt"></i> Edit</a>
</div>
```

And it looks like this:
[desktop view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sini6.png)

However, in mobile devices, the buttons go out of screen a bit as seen in the picture below:
[mobile view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lO13u.png)

So my question is, is there an easy way to convert these button to a drop down that would look something like this:

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.1/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm dropdown-toggle " data-toggle="dropdown" id="5b4f95e9a64b5" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    <i class="fa fa-cog"></i> Options
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="5b4f95e9a64b5" x-placement="bottom-start" style="position: absolute; will-change: transform; top: 0px; left: 0px; transform: translate3d(63px, 31px, 0px);">
    <a href='#' class="dropdown-item"><i class="fa fa-key"></i> Change Password</a>
    <a href='#' class="dropdown-item"><i class="fa fa-pencil-alt"></i> Edit</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I know the usual method of drawing both options and hiding one in mobile, then hide the other one in desktop view. But it seems like overkill if you have a lot of cases.

Any ideas would be really appreciated

Answer (score 5):

Go ahead and create DOM for your dropdown, but set the display for the dropdown to `d-md-none` and the display for the button group to `d-none d-md-flex`. This will cause the dropdown to be displayed for mobile but hidden for desktop and vice-versa for the button group. Take a look at this example:

```html
<!-- css -->
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.1/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<!-- js -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<!-- dropdown for mobile -->
<div class="dropdown d-md-none">
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm dropdown-toggle " data-toggle="dropdown" id="5b4f95e9a64b5" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
  <i class="fa fa-cog"></i> Options
 </button>
 <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="5b4f95e9a64b5" x-placement="bottom-start" style="position: absolute; will-change: transform; top: 0px; left: 0px; transform: translate3d(63px, 31px, 0px);">
  <a href='#' class="dropdown-item"><i class="fa fa-key"></i> Change Password</a>
  <a href='#' class="dropdown-item"><i class="fa fa-pencil-alt"></i> Edit</a>
 </div>
</div>

<!-- button group for desktop -->
<div class="d-none d-md-flex btn-group">
 <a href='#' class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-danger"><i class="fa fa-key"></i> Change Password</a>
 <a href='#' class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-sm "><i class="fa fa-pencil-alt"></i> Edit</a>
</div>
```

Edit - Wow, I didn't realize how old this thread was.